# Как инвертировать таблицу одним запросом

Tags: sql, mysqli

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Eсть таблица в которой записано данные в два столбца (начало, конец) в формате даты, и каждая запись означает, что отрезок времени между этими двумя днями занят. Каким образом можно создать запрос который покажет свободные (незанятые) дни?

Comment: А диапазоны могут соприкасаться или перекрываться?

Comment: да они могут соприкасаться, но что значит перекрываться?

Comment: Ну например (1,3) и (2,4)...

Comment: нет так не могут

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select t_from, t_till
from ( select @start t_from, @start := t_from t_till, @weight needed, @weight := @weight + weight
       from ( select t_from, 1 weight
              from test
              union all
              select t_till, -1
              from test
            ) x, (select @weight := 0, @start := 0) y
       order by CAST(t_from AS DATE)
     ) z
where needed = 0 and t_from > 0 and t_from != t_till;
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c1f890c072971324aeea08b7b502e333)

Comment: select `DateStart`, `DateEnd`
from ( select @start `DateStart`, @start := `DateStart` `DateEnd`, @weight needed, @weight := @weight + weight
       from ( select `DateStart`, 1 weight
              from DateRange
              union all
              select `DateEnd`, -1
              from DateRange
            ) x, (select @weight := 0, @start := 0) y
       order by `DateStart`
     ) z
where needed = 0 and `DateStart` > 0; 
Вернуло 0 строк

Comment: Добавил демонстрацию. Пробуй.

Comment: У меня есть подозрение в моей рукожопости... Можно обьяснить как ето работает? Самому понять сложно

Comment: *Можно обьяснить как ето работает?* Сними внешнюю обёртку с запроса и посмотри, что даёт использование переменных, как они меняются по мере выполнения запроса. Суть проста - разбираем записи на отдельные даты, начало имеет вес +1, конец -1. Сортируем и считаем сумму с накоплением. Где кончается слитный диапазон, там сумма становится нулевой.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Создаем таблицу с диапазоном дат которые будем проверять, например временную, тогда можно будет сделать так:

```
SELECT Day FROM Calendar
WHERE Day NOT IN (SELECT Day FROM DateRange AS dr 
    INNER JOIN Calendar AS c ON c.Day >= dr.DateStart AND c.Day <= dr.DateEnd )
```

[Проверка](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/61ace/2)

Comment: Спасибо сейчас проверю

Comment: а что еще за Calendar? У меня только одна таблица с двумя колонками

Comment: @МиколаМірчук, это как раз та табличка, с диапазоном дат, о которой сказано абзацом выше :) Состоит из одного столбца `Day`.

Comment: К сожелению етот способ не подходит(. У меня есть только одна таблица

Comment: @МиколаМірчук а создать временную `CREATE TABLE #Calendar (Day date);` ?